# Python design - keep track of the number of times a number appears in a sequence, iterating over multiple sequences

Tags: python, text

I am fairly new to programming (python) and am looking for advice on how to best implement this script. I have given it a few gos but I think I might be approaching it incorrectly from the start.

What I have is a text file. It contains multiple lottery draw numbers in lines:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
6, 4, 2, 3, 5
...
```

I would like to read each value in each line, and for each line keep a count of the specific number's occurrence.

Later, after each line is checked and the occurrence is counted, I would like to have the ability to check the balls pulled the least. This means I need to be able to know that after line 1 was checked, balls 6 to 50 were never pulled.

My approach has been to create a script with an object Ball

```
Ball:
def __init__ (self, name):
    Ball.name = name

def count_Occurance()
    Count()
```

Then I read the text file, split it into lines, and split each line into individual values:

```
Read("lottoresults.txt", "r")
line = readline.split("/n")
```

and create and array from it

```
line_array = [line]
```

Then I create an array for all the balls that exist

```
ball_array = range(1,50)
```

Then I run an intersect between the line_array and ball_array

If the ball pulled matched a number in the my_array, I create an instance of the Ball object with the value (v) as it's name:

```
for each v in line_array:
PulledBall = Ball(v)
```

Then I call the method to count it

```
PulledBall.countOccurance()
```

Is this the best way to do it? I am currently learning how to get each of those steps right, but if the overall approach is wrong, I'd rather start over and do it better.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors in it. Have you tried running this?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that - I'm fairly new to programming, and was not at my own pc. I wrote this from memory, sort of shorthand to convey the approach

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from collections import Counter

with open("lottoresults.txt") as inf:
    nums = [int(i) for i in inf.read().replace(",", "").split()]

counts = Counter(nums)
```

Comment: Thanks Hugh - that works real nice but gives me the count of the exact lines. I added "\n" into the section: "inf.read().replace(",", "\n").split()", and it gives me the count of the individual values lines after line.

Comment: That's odd - because when I cut-and-paste this exact code into IDLE (Python 3.5) and run it against a test file, it counts individual numbers (not lines).